# AngularJs passing parameter values to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, controller

My Html:

```
<test-app email="hello@hotmail.com"></test-app>
```

My Directive:

```
.directive('testApp', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        userEmail = '@userEmail'
    },
    templateUrl: 'Form.html'
};
})
```

My Form in another Page:

```
<label> Email </label>
<input type="text" id="email">
```

Issue: I need to get the parameter value , and print it out on the textbox itself.

What i have done: I research on a lot of articles which demonstrated on how to pass directive parameters to controller but they were very complicated.

What i think is the next step:

1) Pass the directive parameter to the controller and then bind the controller to the textbox and set the value of the textbox to be the parameter value.

2) Or is there another way i can do this?

I am stuck on how to proceed on.

Comment: First try to follow directive naming convension(**camelCase**), for example: directive name `makeBold` then use it in template like: `<make-bold ...> </make-bold>`

Comment: @AvneshShakya edited. But that isn't going to help start. Any tips to continue?

Comment: You want `email` value in directive, correct? so try this: `scope: { userEmail:  '@email'},` and in your template: `<input type="text" ng-model="userEmail" id="email">` check about isolated scope in detail [here](https://jsfiddle.net/avnesh2/fzyo5p0t/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=fzyo5p0t)

Comment: i want the email value into the directive then to the controller. As i need to print out the value into the input text box @AvneshShakya

Comment: Ya you will get, see my comment above :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use *attribute string binding* using `@`

1. In *controller* you initialize your `userEmail` variable
2. The *directive* has a `user-email` attribute which loads value into the directive's `userEmail` local scope variable.
3. Using `userEmail:'@'` allows for *string binding* from controller to the directive.

See demo below:

```js
angular.module("app",[]).directive('application', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      userEmail : '@'
    },
    templateUrl: 'Form.html'
  };
}).controller("ctrl",function($scope){
  $scope.userEmail="hello@hotmail.com";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <application user-email="{{userEmail}}"></application>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="Form.html">
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="text" id="email" ng-model="userEmail">
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: your answer is sort of close. But i want the value in the directive which the user might enter straight in for example : <test-app email="test@hotmail.com"></test-app> . I wan the 'test@hotmail.com' to be inserted into the form's textbox

Comment: @JohnTan well, I'm not sure what you are looking for, you can use `<application user-email="test@hotmail.com"></application>` ?

Comment: @JohnTan just following up on this - so you managed to solve the issue? If this answer helped, upvote/accept too, thanks!

Comment: Hi ! sorry. i did not managed to solve this. Is it possible to do it with another way ?? i think its because of my application structure as i have a few templateUrl and it cant pass directly to the controller